# 'Contingent' user interface (DialogNotebook with PopupMenus that depend on previous PopupMenus)

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction, dialog-window

I'm creating a user interface for data entry. It makes sense for the content of certain menu items to depend on the information that has been entered earlier on the form.

In a trivial example, imagine a `DialogWindow` where selecting menu item `"Bill"` results in a `PopupMenu` with the choices `"Running"` or `"Reading"`, while selecting the item `"Susan"` results in different choices.

```
CreateWindow[
  DialogNotebook[DynamicModule[{name, activity, fauxDB, dbRow},
    fauxDB = {<|"name" -> "Bill", 
       "activities" -> {"Running", "Reading"}|>, <|"name" -> "Susan", 
       "activities" -> {"Swimming", "Sleeping"}|>};
    Column@{TextCell["Name: "],
      PopupMenu[Dynamic[name], fauxDB[[All, "name"]]],
      TextCell["Activity: "],
      dbRow = Select[fauxDB, #[[name]] == Dynamic[name] &][[1]];
      PopupMenu[Dynamic[activity], dbRow[["activities"]]],
      ChoiceButtons[{"Enter", "Cancel"}, {DialogReturn[{
          Print[name, " ", activity];
          }]}]
      }]
   ]];
```

The code above doesn't work; how might one create a `DialogNotebook` with variable elements as I describe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `DynamicWrapper` or the second argument of `Dynamic` to take an action after something is done.

Additionaly let me reshape your dataset to association form: `<|name1->activities1,...|>`

```
CreateWindow[ DialogNotebook[ DynamicModule[
   {name, activity, fauxDB, dbRow}
   , 
   fauxDB = {
     <|"name" -> "Bill", "activities" -> {"Running", "Reading"}|>, 
     <|"name" -> "Susan", "activities" -> {"Swimming", "Sleeping"}|>
   };

   fauxDB = GroupBy[fauxDB, Key["name"] -> Key["activities"], First];

   name = First @ Keys @ fauxDB;

   dbRow = fauxDB[name];

   Column @ {
     TextCell["Name: "],
     PopupMenu[ Dynamic[name, (*now the important part*)
       {Automatic, (dbRow = fauxDB[name]; activity = First@dbRow) &}
       ], 
       fauxDB // Keys
     ],
     TextCell["Activity: "],
       (*additional dynamic to track dbRow changes, also important*)
     Dynamic @ PopupMenu[ Dynamic[activity], dbRow]
     ,
     ChoiceButtons[
      {"Enter", "Cancel"},
      {DialogReturn[{Print[name, " ", activity];}]}
      ]}
   ]]
 ]
```

Comment: Took a bit of fussing in my real application but a variation on this approach worked, thank you. Why did you reshape the dataset? I always separate fields for the sake of debugging and later maintenance. Am I missing something?

Comment: @MichaelStern unless it's really big I like to use different representations of datasets depending of the context. Here `fauxDB[name]` is shorter/more readable than querying with `Select`. I'd say at the end it's a matter of taste.